# Calculating time elasped and putting it in Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds format in javascript where time elapsed updates every second

Tags: javascript, datetime, elapsedtime

I am trying to compute time elapsed between a set date time object and current time. I want it to be able to appear in this format DD:HH:MM:SS where DD is day, HH is Hours, MM is minutes,SS is Seconds.I am able to get the total day, total hours, total minutes and total seconds but i am not sure how to format it the way I want. Please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>timer</title>   
</head>
<body >
<div id ="time" name ="timer"></div>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {

  let seconds = 1000 ;
  let minutes = seconds * 60;
  let hours = minutes * 60;
  let days = hours * 24;
  let years = days * 365;


  const startDateTime = new Date("June 2, 2019 12:36:10 AM");
  const newDateTime = new Date();

  let timeDiff = newDateTime - startDateTime;

  let totalSeconds = Math.round(timeDiff/seconds);


  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = totalSeconds;
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to use a library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com), but if you wanted to do this in plain Javascript you could just divide the number of total seconds with the division parameters you already defined and pad them with a zero when they're less than ten.

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

const seconds = 1000;
const minutes = seconds * 60;
const hours = minutes * 60;
const days = hours * 24;
const years = days * 365;

function myTimer() {
  const startDateTime = new Date("June 2, 2019 12:36:10 AM");
  const newDateTime = new Date();

  let elapsedMilliseconds = newDateTime - startDateTime;
  
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = 
  `${formatElapsedTime(elapsedMilliseconds, days)}:${formatElapsedTime(elapsedMilliseconds, hours, 24)}:${formatElapsedTime(elapsedMilliseconds, minutes, 60)}:${formatElapsedTime(elapsedMilliseconds, seconds, 60)}`;
}

function formatElapsedTime(elapsedtime, timeunit, base) {
  let time = base ? (elapsedtime / timeunit) % base : elapsedtime / timeunit;
  time = Math.floor(time);
  time = time < 10 ? '0' + time : time;
  return time;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>timer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="time" name="timer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```